# Why is there this huge margin in my webpage

Tags: html, css, margin

I just made a for and I'm trying to put 2 divs next to each other in another div but there is this huge margin that won't let it happen I'm trying to figure it out but I can't get anything to work. please help me I have been trying to figure this out for hours. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHAT1.png

just look at the /*contact page*/ in the CSS section that's the only code that I'm trying to fix. its only on the bottom.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap");
* {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #222;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #192841;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 50px 0 100px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
nav .logo {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul li {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul li a.active,
nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #111;
  background: #fff;
}
nav .menu-btn i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  nav {
    padding: 0 40px 0 50px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 920px) {
  nav .menu-btn i {
    display: block;
  }
  #click:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }
  nav ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    background: #111;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul {
    left: 0;
  }
  nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 40px 0;
  }
  nav ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -100%;
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
  }
  #click:checked ~ ul li a {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav ul li a.active,
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background: none;
    color: cyan;
  }
}

/* Footer */

.footer {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;

  padding-bottom: 1%;
}

.footer {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Footer */

/*home page*/

.contentHeader {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .contentHeader {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    padding: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
}

.AboutOnHomepage {
  padding: 5% 10%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 4%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: justify;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .AboutOnHomepage {
    padding-top: 15%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .AboutOnHomepage p {
    text-align: justify;
  }
}

.AboutOnHomepage h2 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.mainUpdate {
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mainUpdate {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.recentUpdates {
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .recentUpdates {
    padding-top: 20%;
  }
}

.up1Home {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.up2Home {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.up3Home {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 3%;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.updateHome1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.par1 {
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-left: 5%;
}

.img1 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .updateHome1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .par1 {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .img1 {
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.updateHome2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
  margin-top: 0%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.par2 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.img2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .updateHome2 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .par2 {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .img2 {
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.updateHome3 {
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 0%;
}

.par3 {
  padding-top: 2%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.img3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .updateHome3 {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .par3 {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .img3 {
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

/*home page*/

/*Google form*/

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .content {
    padding-bottom: 10%;
  }
}

.googleFormHeading {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
  color: #1b1b1b;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .googleFormHeading {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2%;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
  }
}

.bothGoogleForms {
  padding-top: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.googleFormTv {
  padding-left: 4%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.googleFormTv iframe {
  width: 700px;
  height: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.googleFormMovie {
  padding-left: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.googleFormMovie iframe {
  width: 700px;
  height: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .bothGoogleForms {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .googleFormTv {
    text-align: center;
    width: 90%;
    padding-bottom: 11%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  }

  .googleFormTv iframe {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2%;
    height: 976px;
  }

  .googleFormMovie {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 11%;
    margin-bottom: 15%;
  }

  .googleFormMovie iframe {
    padding-left: 2%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 976px;
  }
}

/*Google form*/

/*Contact Page*/

.ContactPageAll {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.contactForm {
  color: #111;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
}

.contactForm input,
textarea,
label {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.contactForm input,
textarea,
button {
  display: block;
  padding: 4%;
  width: 120%;
  background-color: white;
  color: #111;
}

.contactFormName {
  padding-bottom: 2%;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.socials {
  width: 55%;
  display: inline-block;
}

/*Contact Page*/ ;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Created By CodingNepal -->
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Responsive Navigation Menu</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo"> Reviews</div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="click" />
      <label for="click" class="menu-btn">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="myTvShows.html">Tv-Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="topTvShows.html">Top Tv-Shows</a></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="ContactPageAll">
      <div class="socials">fklghliabgljglabg</div>
      <div class="contactForm">
        <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@aol.com" method="POST">
          <label class="contactFormName" for="name">Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            required
            placeholder="Enter Your Name"
          />

          <label class="contactFormEmail" for="Email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            required
            placeholder="Email Address"
          />

          <label
            class="contactForMessage"
            for="message"
            placeholder="Write Your Message here"
            >What Do You Want to Say:</label
          >
          <textarea
            name="message"
            id="message"
            placeholder="Write Your mEssage here"
            cols="30"
            rows="10"
          ></textarea>

          <input
            type="hidden"
            name="_subject"
            value="New submission From My website"
          />
          <input
            type="hidden"
            name="_next"
            value="https://sunnymoon25.github.io/mainPages/thanks.html"
          />
          <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false" />
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

just look at the /*contact page*/ section that's the only code that I'm trying to fix

Comment: Can you do right answer on my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not margin this actual width as you have given [image]

If you want to side by side div so you need to add below html and CSS so you get as you want output.

```
<div class="ContactPageAll">
      <div class="socials">fklghliabgljglabg</div>
      <div class="contactForm">
        <form action="https://formsubmit.co/myemail@aol.com" method="POST">
          <label class="contactFormName" for="name">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" required="" placeholder="Enter Your Name">

          <label class="contactFormEmail" for="Email">Email:</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" required="" placeholder="Email Address">

          <label class="contactForMessage" for="message" placeholder="Write Your Message here">What Do You Want to Say:</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write Your mEssage here" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

          <input type="hidden" name="_subject" value="New submission From My website">
          <input type="hidden" name="_next" value="https://sunnymoon25.github.io/mainPages/thanks.html">
          <input type="hidden" name="_captcha" value="false">
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and put css below like

```
.ContactPageAll {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.socials {
    width: 50%;
}
.contactForm {
    width: 50%;
}
.contactForm input, textarea, button {
    display: block;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: #111;
}
```

here I have taken 50:50 width, you can take any width and update it as you want